# Apache2: direct url in subdirectory to its parent directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2, symlink

I'm having an issue with Apache2, relating to my file structure. On my image server, I have a symlink to another drive with the name images. As such, the url for an image is 
`https://img.exampleurl.com/images/items/image.jpg`

Is it possible to have this change, so to access the same image I can use
`https://img.exampleurl.com/items/image.jpg`?

As far as I can tell, mod_rewrite in .htaccess is the way to go, but I can't work out how to get this working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this using mod_rewrite, at the top of your `.htaccess` located in the root of `img.exampleurl.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^items/[\w-]+\.jpg$ /images/$0 [L]
```

Assumptions:

- `img.exampleurl.com` is separate from your main (non-image) domain.
- Images are all `.jpg` (as in your example).
- Image basenames consist of the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore) or `-` (hyphen).